# JPA/EclipseLink: select before update - changes without optimistic locking overwritten

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, optimistic-locking

I use JPA/EclipseLink in my project for most updates, but some mass-updates on the db should change data in background. The user should not get an optimistic lock exception, if data is changed in background while editing some data. So the mass update does not update the version field.

If I load a entity to display it to the user and persist it afterwars, the changes made in mass update are overwritten. EclipseLink does not only update the values changed by the user, it does a select before update and changes also fields which were changed by the mass update between loading and merging entity.

Is there a possibility to get only fields updated, which where changed by the user and ignore other fields updated by the mass update?

Comment: How is Eclipselink supposed to guess the user's *intent* (i.e. leaving a property intact vs setting it to a new value, which just happens to be the same as some old value, a while back)? If you keep track of the user actions (i.e. which fields were modified), you should patch the entity instead of a full-on `merge`. Just fetch the entity by its `id` an update only those fields that were touched by the user

Comment: EclipseLink certainly only pushes only changes and uses change tracking, but this requires that you read the object from an EntityManager context and use that instance for your changes. If you serialize it anywhere (Ie rest) that you would need to use a merge call, it won't work: JPA's contract on merge is that what you pass in overwrites the data within that context, and is likely what you are seeing - it reads in the latest data for the managed instance and overwrites with the data from your instance. Change tracking with weaving might help, but it'll depend on the serialization mechanism.